# how to access values from result returned by eloquent model in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to access the data which is returned by eloquent model in my code. but i am making mistakes.
I need help to sort out this , My code

```
public function success(Request $request)
{
    $paymentstatus=$request->input('status');
    $transactionid=$request->input('txnid');
    Ticket::where('transactionid',$transactionid)->update(['paymentstatus'=>$paymentstatus]);
    $ticketdata=Ticket::where('transactionid',$transactionid)->get();


    $message="Ticket#:{{$ticketdata->ticketid}}";

    SmsController::sendsms($request->input('phone'),$message); //use of sms controller class & function to send sms
    return $request->all();
}
```

I am getting error for this line, I doubt that it isn't correctly accessed .

```
$message="Ticket#:{{$ticketdata->ticketid}}";
```

Please help me rectify this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using get request,if you using get method, it will take more that one row.So if you use get first you need to foreach,otherwise you have to user first method.Follow my code

```
public function success(Request $request)
{
$paymentstatus=$request->input('status');
$transactionid=$request->input('txnid');
Ticket::where('transactionid',$transactionid)->update(['paymentstatus'=>$paymentstatus]);
$ticketdata=Ticket::where('transactionid',$transactionid)->first();


$message="Ticket#:{{$ticketdata->ticketid}}";

SmsController::sendsms($request->input('phone'),$message); //use of sms controller class & function to send sms
return $request->all();
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, when i changed get() to first(). Thanks buddy